# Redirect Javascript logs to remote server

Tags: logging, react-native

I'm trying to catch `console.log` logs in my React Native app to send the to a remote server (I'm trying Papertrail).

I know they are displayed to `stderr` but I want to send them to the Papertrail's server. I managed to send native logs (with the Papertrail's wrapper around CocoaLumberjack) but I don't know how to do this for javascript logs..

I tried to override default `NSLog` but React Native's logs uses the low-level API `ASL`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RCTAddLogFunction` https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6603cef95cd30fcc05330707d4ce10a2c4e22046/React/Base/RCTLog.h#L107 (or `RCTSetLogFunction`) and do what you need with the message.

Comment: Do you know if is it possible to do this on Android?